# Possible Chainlink VRF returns two same randomnesses in one request?

Tags: random, generator, chainlink

as the title, i am thinking if it's possible that Chainlink VRF returns two same randomnesses in one request? As of "random", i assume the answer is YES. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For each request, Chainlink VRF generates one or more random values and cryptographic proof of how those values were determined. It is unlikely that a Chainlink VRF would return the same randomness in one request.

Comment: DevMarine is right on. To clarify, yes, it's possible. It's improbable.